# Изменение стилей блока если в нем присутствует класс

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Есть категория, в которой есть листинг товаров.

У некоторых товаров есть класс `bad_sal`. Нужно сделать так что бы у тех товаров у которых есть этот класс была рамка.

Делал так, но работает не правильно, делает рамки на всех товарах если на странице есть данный класс.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".bad_sal").length > 0) {
    $(".v-products-card__item-wrap").css({
      "border": "1px solid #ff4900"
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем тут *Jquery* не ясно.

```css
.v-products-card__item-wrap {
  margin: 5px;
}

.v-products-card__item-wrap .bad_sal {
  border: 1px solid #ff4900;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-products-card__item-wrap">
  <div class="bad_sal">
    с рамкой
  </div>
</div>

<div class="v-products-card__item-wrap">
  <div>
    без рамки
  </div>
</div>

<div class="v-products-card__item-wrap">
  <div class="bad_sal">
    опять с рамкой
  </div>
</div>
```

Если имелось в виду рамка у предка:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bad_sal").closest('.v-products-card__item-wrap').addClass('bordered-product');
});
```

```css
.v-products-card__item-wrap {
  margin: 5px;
}


.v-products-card__item-wrap.bordered-product {
  border: 1px solid #ff4900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="v-products-card__item-wrap">
  <div class="bad_sal">
    с рамкой
  </div>
</div>

<div class="v-products-card__item-wrap">
  <div>
    без рамки
  </div>
</div>

<div class="v-products-card__item-wrap">
  <div class="bad_sal">
    опять с рамкой
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы видимо не поняли суть вопроса. Нужно в рамку загнать не bad_sal а .v-products-card__item-wrap. bad_sal это типо скидка, еслди есть скидка у товара то подсветить рамку товара

Comment: @ilyaaa521 давайте разберем тело вопроса: У некоторых **товаров** есть класс `bad_sal`. ->>> сделать так что бы у тех **товаров** у которых есть этот класс была рамка. По логике, именно у товаров есть класс,а не у чего-то другого. Где тут сказано про v-products-card__item-wrap?  Давайте корректно сформулируйте вопрос с разметкой и будем от этого отталкиваться тогда

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  if($(".bad_sal").length>0) {
   $(this).parent(".v-products-card__item-wrap").css({"border": "1px solid #ff4900"});
  }
 }); нужно что то вроде этого

Comment: @ilyaaa521 посмотри второй пример. Не "нужно что то вроде этого", а разметку надо добавлять в вопрос и корректно описать))

Comment: То что надо ) Спасибо большое!